# Does Java use the one byte long ASCII Code set for character representation?

Tags: java, ascii

I'm just starting with Java and trying to understand the basic concepts.  I was asked the question, "Does Java use the one byte long ASCII Code set for character representation?"

I know that Java uses Unicode which includes ASCII, but is ASCII one byte long?

Comment: In these kinds of questions you must be as precise as possible. In what sense do you know that Java "uses Unicode"? Java has a char primitive type, and a String class, and Java source code elements are made up of specified Unicode characters, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII is a 7-bit representation, so yes, every ASCII character can fit in a `byte`.

However, a Java `char` is 16 bits. It's a UTF-16 code unit. So if you have a `char` array of 100 characters, that will require 200 bytes (plus object overhead) even if every character is only ASCII. From [section 3.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1):

> The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding.